# What is the better way to select columns in dataframe?

Tags: pandas

I'm now studying tutorial about pandas and author mentioned(but not explained yet), that if you want to select some columns from dataframe the only best way is to use

`df.loc[:,[list_of_column_names]]`.

And another more convenient way for myself `df[[list_of_column_names]]` may cause some issues, and not recomended.

But why?
What kind of issues can I'll catch with second option?

Also, what is your best way to select columns from dataframe?

Thx

Comment: think about the internals of how objects are dereferenced.  Every level of abstraction adds convenience but brings in a set of restrictions. `df.loc` is effectively giving you direct access to underlying NumPy array.  Whereas `df[[]]` is giving your a reference an object that accesses underlying NumPy array.  The issue is that the underlying NumPy array can change and then there can be an issue with the way the object references it becoming *dead*

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify for myself and maybe find hidden issues.

In case, when using chaining indexing, it's not totally clear what kind of object we receive in response.

If use just `df[column_name]` we receive a view to original dataframe. But in case of boolean slicing e.g. `df[column name < 5]` we receive a copy of original dataframe. And all further changings in this case don't save in original dataframe.

So, to conclude, if you need to save all your manipulations to original dataframe - use `df.loc[(boolean_rows_slicing or :), [list_of _columns]]`. All slicing operations in one.

And if you NOT need to save work, use `.copy()`.
E.g. `df.loc[(boolean_rows_slicing or :), [list_of _columns]].copy()`

Maybe I'm wrong. And in that case, please, let me know. Thx